# Does ffmpeg version 0.5 configured on linux support encoding using Theora codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg-theora

I have configured, compiled a FFmpeg source code version 0.5 with versions as below:

```
FFmpeg version 0.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
```

on a linux host.

When I try to encode a raw yuv video using this version using theora codec by giving options as :

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 352x288 -r 30 -i foreman_352_x280_420.yuv -an -vcodec libtheora theora1.ogg
```

It gives an error: `Unknown encoder 'libtheora'`

But when i use the same command in a FFmpeg windows executable ( whose version is FFmpeg version SVN-r12665) it encoded to a theora video properly.

1. Doesnt ffmpeg version 0.5 on linux support theora encoder?
2. Which version for linux setup,would support theora encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does if built with `--enable-libtheora`.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `-vcodec` with `target` option

Comment: Can you please extend your answer?